# vs code remove white box in editor interface

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Basically when I open a file on VScode, a new one or one that I already have, it splits the editor into two, but one half is blank, almost like it was a preview because as I scroll down the code, it follows, but empty....

This "preview blank space" occupies half the screen and it's really bothering me... Could you please help? I think it's a **command i have to execute** because I've tried to reset the settings and even uninstall the VS code and it stays the same.
It doesn't have any close options (nor the right or left button of the mouse) and I can't move it anywhere (nor open a file on it). Also, I don't think it's editor split because I already did and undo that and it doesn't solve

If anyone knows how to fix it, I would really appreciate because I can't find a solution anywhere and I'm desperate..

Comment: Try disabling all extensions and see if it goes away. If so, it's caused by some extension. If it stays, I would open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Can you show some pictures

Comment: I already fixed it! It was a setting that somehow was changed! The settings "editor.scrollbar.horizontalScrollbarSize": 500,  "editor.scrollbar.verticalScrollbarSize": 500 --- they were changed to 500 when they are suppost to be like 12